# Swift 3 Cocoa: use QuickLook to preview file in OS X

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, quicklook

Xcode 8.3.2 I don't find QLPreviewPanel in the command list and I don't know how to do (which command must be used) to display a file preview in a ViewController.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you will need to add the `import Quartz`  statement to your `NSViewCOntroller`. Second step is to add `QLPreviewPanelDataSource, QLPreviewPanelDelegate` to its declaration. Next you just need to get a reference of the shared [QLPreviewPanel](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartz/qlpreviewpanel), make the view controller its  `dataSource` and `delegate` and make its window key and order front.

You will need also to add  numberOfPreviewItems and previewItemAt methods to your controller. You can do it as follow:

```
import Quartz

class ViewController: NSViewController,  QLPreviewPanelDataSource, QLPreviewPanelDelegate {

    @IBAction func button(_ sender: NSButton) {
        if let sharedPanel = QLPreviewPanel.shared() {
            sharedPanel.delegate = self
            sharedPanel.dataSource = self
            sharedPanel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        }
    }

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in panel: QLPreviewPanel!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func previewPanel(_ panel: QLPreviewPanel!, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem! {
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("yourImageAtTheDocs.png")
        return url as QLPreviewItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I inserted :
import Cocoa
import QuickLook
import Quartz
and than
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDelegate,NSCollectionViewDataSource, QLPreviewPanelDataSource, QLPreviewPanelDelegate {....
and other instructions. I have a button made to invoke the preview. This button open a new view controller, called SecondViewController and present in main storyboard, in show mode. Do I need to insert code in SecondViewController.swift?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Apples [QuickLookDownloader](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/QuickLookDownloader/Introduction/Intro.html) Demo uses Obj-C. I've created a Swift Versiob which is basically the implementation of @Leo Dabus answer in a Demo Project: [Panel and Popover example](https://github.com/Deitsch/QLPreviewView-example)